# cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'reLayout' angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-isotope, prettyphoto

Using `isotope` and `prettyPhoto` to create my gallery view with angular `js`, but getting the **error cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'reLayout'** Am loading my gallery view in controller as below:

**index.html**

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap", "slickCarousel"]).
config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when("/home", {
    templateUrl: "partial views/home.html"
  })
}).controller("portfolioController", function($scope, $location) {
  //Portfolio
  $scope.$watch("$viewContentLoaded", function() {
    "use strict";
    var $container = $('.portfolio'),
      $items = $container.find('.portfolio-item'),
      portfolioLayout = 'fitRows';

    if ($container.hasClass('portfolio-centered')) {
      portfolioLayout = 'masonry';
    }
    var init = false;
    $container.isotope({
      filter: '*',
      animationEngine: 'best-available',
      layoutMode: portfolioLayout,
      animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
      },
      masonry: {}
    }, refreshWaypoints());

    function refreshWaypoints() {
      init = true;
      setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
    }

    $('nav.portfolio-filter ul a').on('click', function() {
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
      }, refreshWaypoints());
      $('nav.portfolio-filter ul a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      return false;
    });

    function getColumnNumber() {
      var winWidth = $(window).width(),
        columnNumber = 1;

      if (winWidth > 1200) {
        columnNumber = 5;
      } else if (winWidth > 950) {
        columnNumber = 4;
      } else if (winWidth > 600) {
        columnNumber = 3;
      } else if (winWidth > 400) {
        columnNumber = 2;
      } else if (winWidth > 250) {
        columnNumber = 1;
      }
      return columnNumber;
    }

    function setColumns() {
      var winWidth = $(window).width(),
        columnNumber = getColumnNumber(),
        itemWidth = Math.floor(winWidth / columnNumber);

      $container.find('.portfolio-item').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          width: itemWidth + 'px'
        });
      });
    }

    function setPortfolio() {
      setColumns();
      if (init) $container.isotope('reLayout');
    }

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
      setPortfolio();
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      setPortfolio();
    });
  });
})
```

**home.html**

```
<div id="portfoliowrap" ng-controller="portfolioController">
    <h3>LATEST WORKS</h3>
    <div class="portfolio-centered">
        <div class="recentitems portfolio">
            <div class="portfolio-item graphic-design">
                <div class="he-wrap tpl6">
                    <img src="/img/portfolio/portfolio_09.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="he-view">
                        <div class="bg a0" data-animate="fadeIn">
                            <h3 class="a1" data-animate="fadeInDown">A Graphic Design Item</h3>
                            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio_09.jpg" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                            <a href="single-project.html" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        </div><!-- he bg -->
                    </div><!-- he view -->
                </div><!-- he wrap -->
            </div><!-- end col-12 -->
            <div class="portfolio-item books">
                <div class="he-wrap tpl6">
                    <img src="/img/portfolio/portfolio_10.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="he-view">
                        <div class="bg a0" data-animate="fadeIn">
                            <h3 class="a1" data-animate="fadeInDown">A Book Design Item</h3>
                            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio_10.jpg" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                            <a href="single-project.html" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        </div><!-- he bg -->
                    </div><!-- he view -->
                </div><!-- he wrap -->
            </div><!-- end col-12 -->

        </div><!-- portfolio -->
    </div><!-- portfolio container -->
</div><!--/Portfoliowrap -->
```

As you see, I've also used `$scope.$watch("$viewContentLoaded",` to make sure view is loaded. But still getting above error. `Isotope` is working fine, but `prettyphoto` isn't working which may be because of this error. Hope to get some guidance on this.

Comment: Always initialize plugins in directives. `$viewContentLoaded` will not assure you that all rendering is done. Should never have any dom related code in controllers. I believe there is already  an angular module that wraps isotope ... http://mankindsoftware.github.io/angular-isotope/

Comment: @charlietfl.. I'll check it once and let know.. :)

Comment: Also don't think you can `$watch` for `$viewContentLoaded` , it is an event and you would use `$on`. Irregardless approach is all wrong...need directives

Comment: @charlietfl.. Thanks much.. I've solved it.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with the help of **[@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)** - *[Thanks much buddy]*, I was able to resolve this with the help of `directives`. Below is the sample code.

**app.js**

```
angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap", "slickCarousel"]).
config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when("/home", {
    templateUrl: "partial views/home.html"
  })
}).controller("portfolioController", function ($scope, $location) {
    //Portfolio
    $scope.update = function () {
        $scope.imgList = [{
            url: "img/portfolio/portfolio_09.jpg",
            href: "assets/img/portfolio/portfolio_09.jpg",
            desc: "A Graphic Design Item"
        },
        {
            url: "/img/portfolio/portfolio_02.jpg",
            href: "assets/img/portfolio/portfolio_02.jpg",
            desc: "A Web Design Item"
        },
        {
            url: "/img/portfolio/portfolio_03.jpg",
            href: "assets/img/portfolio/portfolio_03.jpg",
            desc: "A Web Design Item"
        }];
    }
    $scope.update();
}).directive('isoRepeat', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            items: '=isoRepeat'
        },
        template: '<div class="portfolio-item graphic-design" ng-repeat="item in items"><div class="he-wrap tpl6"><img ng-src="{{item.url}}" /><div class="he-view">'
                  + '<div class="bg a0" data-animate="fadeIn">'
                  + '<h3 class="a1" data-animate="fadeInDown">{{item.desc}}</h3>'
                  + '<a data-rel="prettyPhoto" ng-href="{{item.href}}" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>'
                  + '<!--<a href="single-project.html" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->'
                  + '</div><!-- he bg -->'
                  + '</div><!-- he view -->'
                  + '</div><!-- he wrap --></div><!-- end col-12 -->',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var options = {
                filter: '*',
                animationEngine: 'best-available',
                itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows',
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
            };

            element.isotope(options);
            scope.getColumnNumber = function () {
                var winWidth = $(window).width(),
                columnNumber = 1;

                if (winWidth > 1200) {
                    columnNumber = 5;
                } else if (winWidth > 950) {
                    columnNumber = 4;
                } else if (winWidth > 600) {
                    columnNumber = 3;
                } else if (winWidth > 400) {
                    columnNumber = 2;
                } else if (winWidth > 250) {
                    columnNumber = 1;
                }
                return columnNumber;
            }

            scope.setColumns = function () {
                var winWidth = $(window).width(),
                columnNumber = scope.getColumnNumber(),
                itemWidth = Math.floor(winWidth / columnNumber);

                $(element).find('.portfolio-item').each(function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        width: itemWidth + 'px'
                    });
                });
            }

            scope.setPortfolio = function () {
                scope.setColumns();
                $(element).isotope('reLayout');
            }
            $(window).on('resize', function () {
                scope.setPortfolio();
            });
            scope.$watch('items', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.isotope('reloadItems').isotope();
                    scope.setPortfolio();
                });
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="recentitems portfolio" data-iso-repeat="imgList">
</div><!-- portfolio -->
```

Comment: Looks much better. Might want to also remove window listener in `scope.$on('$destroy', func...`

Comment: @charlietfl.. Sorry.. where from??

Comment: Inside directive `scope.$on('$destroy', function(){ $(window).off('resize');})`. If other resize used elsewhere in page can namespace the event also

Comment: Oh.. Alright.. point noted.. :) thank you.. :) Mind if I ask small doubt here?

Comment: go ahead... if asking why remove it it's probably not critical but will be there for the life of the page even though the element will be gone when switch routes. Have to do same with things like `$interval` when it's only applicable to part of page in a specific route

Comment: :) So.. I am trying to implement prettyPhoto in this now.. If you see the template of isotope above you see an `anchor` i.e. `<a data-rel="prettyPhoto"`  in between.. I used **[this directive](https://gist.github.com/fannheyward/7560525)** and added it as `<a data-rel="prettyPhoto" prettyp` in template.. But it renders as `<a data-rel="prettyPhoto" prettyp=""`.. How can I use this??

Comment: The `prettyp=""` should work the same as without `=""`. All angular cares about is the attribute exists if the `restrict` of directive is `"A"` for attribute

Comment: Oh yea.. cleared that @charlietfl.. I was using `data-rel` in anchor whereas I was supposed to use `rel`.. Thanks so much once again.. :) Happy coding.. :)